# return statement confusion..I am not sure about the syntax

Tags: python, probability

```
def most_common(dices):
    """
    Returns the dices that are most common
    In case of a draw, returns the lowest number
    """
    counts = Counter(dices)
    keep = max(counts.iteritems(), key=operator.itemgetter(1))[0]
    return [keep] * counts[keep]
```

I am confused by the syntax of the return.

1. What is `[keep]`? It looks like an array bracket with nothing else.
2. `counts[keep]` looks like `vector_name[index]`. Is that right?

Lastly, why would it be multiplying the two in the return statement? Thanks for all your help.

Comment: Might be somthing like this `>>> l = [2] >>> [3] * l[0]`  get `[3, 3]`.

Answer (score 3):

Let's go through step by step.

First we import:

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> import operator
```

These are our example dices:

```
>>> dices = [3, 5, 6, 2, 3, 4, 3, 3]
```

The `Counter` counts how many of each are there:

```
>>> counts = Counter(dices)
>>> counts 
Counter({3: 4, 2: 1, 4: 1, 5: 1, 6: 1})
```

This gets the dice with the maximum count:

```
>>> keep = max(counts.iteritems(), key=operator.itemgetter(1))[0]
>>> keep
3
```

BTW, you get the same number with:

```
>>> keep = counts.most_common()[0][0]
```

Put `keep` into a list:

```
>>> [keep]
[3]
```

This dictionary lookup returns how many times the `3` appears:

```
>>> counts[keep]
4
```

You can multiply a list with an integer:

```
>>> [3] * 4
[3, 3, 3, 3]
```

or:

```
>>> [keep] * counts[keep]
[3, 3, 3, 3]
```

So the result is the most common dice as many times as it appears in the original list of dices.

Answer (score 0):

`[keep]` is a list with a single element (`keep`), e.g. if `keep = 4`, `[keep]` is `[4]`.

In python you can multiply a `list` by a number:

```
>>> l = [1]
>>> l * 3
[1, 1, 1]
```

So `[keep] * counts[keep]` is basically:

```
[keep, keep, ..., keep]
```

And you have `counts[keep]` times `keep`.

In your case, `keep` is the most common value in `dices`(`1` to `6` for a standard dice), and `counts[keep]` is the number of times that value appears in `dices`.

If `dices` is `[1, 1, 2, 1, 3, 3]`, the most common value is `1` and it appears `3` times so `keep = 1` and `counts[keep] = 3`, thus you get `[1, 1, 1]`.